# Cronjob disappears whenever I restart apache2

Tags: 14.04, apache2

I am relatively new to linux and apache.

I edited root's crontab by logging-in as root and then typing `crontab -e` but my cronjob disappears from the crontab whenever I restart the apache2 server.

Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: How did you edit your crontab?

Comment: I logged in as root and used crontab -e.

Answer (score 1):

Oops! You've fallen afoul of the fact that Ubuntu (Debian?) handles `root` crontab not via `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` (which is the file you create, with `crontab -e`), but through `/etc/crontab`, which offers the system more flexibility, and, via a slightly different format, the ability to run periodic jobs as any user.

From `/etc/crontab`:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.
```

So, abandon `crontab -e` as `root`, and follow `/etc/crontab`

I haven't figured out why `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` gets deleted, but since it's not the Right Way, I don't think it matters.